# Database Update issue, couldn't update

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm trying to update the flag value to 1 in my database, but it doesn't work and I don't know what is wrong with it. I execute the same SQL statement in my SQLAdministrator and it works. But it doesn't work in my php code.

```
   <?php

$dc = $_POST['discount_code'];
$success = "success";
$fail = "fail";

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect to the database! ' . mysql_error());
}

/*Accessing the database */
$db_selected = mysql_select_db("db", $con);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Database error!' . mysql_error());
}
else{

    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM discount_code WHERE disc_code = '$dc'") or die(mysql_error()); 
    $info = mysql_fetch_array($data); 

    if($info['flag'] == "0"){
        $res = mysql_query($con,"UPDATE discount_code SET flag=1 WHERE disc_code='$dc'");
    }
    if($info['flag'] === "1"){
        echo $fail;
    }
}

?>
<form action="" method="post" name="disc_code_form" >
<input type="text" name="discount_code" size="25"></input>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: First, you might want to remove the `===` comparison in the fail section, given you try to update it to a `1` and not a `'1'` I assume it is a number, and your comparison tries to evaluate a string. That might also be why it isn't echoing out the fail message. On that note, any errors coming out of the script, or just runs but doesn't update?

Comment: Use a `print_r($info)`.

Comment: reduce to `UPDATE discount_code SET flag=1 WHERE disc_code='$dc' AND flag=0` ?

Comment: @cske it completely reduces his code. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($info['flag'] == "0"){
    echo 'Updating..'; //so you know whether this condition met or not
    $res = mysql_query($con,"UPDATE discount_code SET flag=1 WHERE disc_code='$dc'");
}

// run select statement again to get the updated row
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM discount_code WHERE disc_code = '$dc'") or die(mysql_error()); 
$info = mysql_fetch_array($data);

if($info['flag'] == "1"){
    echo $fail;
}
```